# Pass parameter as key index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, switch-statement

I have an Object festivals which looks like this:

```
Object {friday: Object}
    friday: Object
        amazon: Object
            band: Object
```

now I have a function:

```
function newAct(band, date, startTime, endTime, stage){
  var act = new Object();
  switch(date){
     case "friday":
         switch(stage){
            case "amazon":
                festival.friday.amazon.band= new Object();

                break;
         }
         break;
   }
   return act;
 }
```

at the line:

```
 festival.friday.amazon.band= new Object();
```

I want to have my parameter 'band' inserted (as a new property of the Amazon Object).
How to do this?

**EDIT**

It's not about the value of the property band. It's about the naming of the property band. I want to name it after the parameter. 
newAct("Suicide Silence", "friday", 19:30, 20:30, "StageTwo"); So now the property would be Suicide_Silence so you get:

```
festival.friday.amazon.Suicide_Silence = new Object();
```

Comment: festival.friday.amazon.band = band; ?
or festival.firday.amazon = { 'band':band }?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong in the code above?

Comment: It's not about the value of the property band.
It's about the naming of the property band. I want to name it after the paramter.
newAct("Suicide Silence", "friday", 19:30, 20:30, "StageTwo");
So now the property would be Suicide_Silence so you get:
festival.friday.amazon.Suicide_Silence = new Object();

Comment: How about `festival[date][stage][band.replace(' ', '_')] = {}` + NullReference checks and a better property name formater than the simple `replace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this, then?

```
var bandname = "Suicide_Silence";
festival.friday.amazon[bandname] = new Object();
```

Btw, I do recommend using Object Literal notation `{}` instead of `new Object()`

Answer (score 0):

The `arguments` object is not an array, although it looks like it. To convert `arguments` to an array, you can do:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```